# Manage Redis for mulitple sites on single domain

Tags: redis, phpredis

I'm hosting several websites on single domain.
Is there any solution to create different redis database with different password for different website like sql database.

Answer (score 1):

Just run multiple Redis instances on the same server, each with a separate configuration (and a different port).

Answer (score 0):

Redis provides database number from 0 to 15 ( 16 databases by default), that would be good enough to provide you namespacing in a single redis instance.
In case you need more, you can edit your redis.conf.

```
# Set the number of databases. The default database is DB 0, you can select
# a different one on a per-connection basis using SELECT <dbid> where
# dbid is a number between 0 and 'databases'-1
databases 16
```

Comment: Is there any way to set different password for different database of redis?
Currently for all database single password is set.

Comment: No, there isn't and do not use shared/numbered databases because they block each other.